# ldconfig includes libraries from default path also when i have a customized ld-<me>.so.conf

Tags: linux, linker

I have cross compiled libraries and a linux loader.
I have placed a custom ld-.so.conf under /etc , The conf file has a path that contains all the cross compiled library and the loader.

But when i run ldconfig,

ldconfig -C /etc/ld-.so.cache -f /etc/ld-.so.conf

All the system libraries and their paths are present in the cache file.
I need the cache file generated to contain only my cross compiled libraries.

Strace of ldconfig operation is as below:

> strace /opt/me/ldconfig -C /etc/ld-me.so.cache -f /etc/ld-me.so.conf
>   execve("/opt/me/ldconfig", ["/opt/me/ldc"..., "-C",
>   "/etc/ld-me.so.cache", "-f", "/etc/ld-me.so.conf"], [/* 38 vars */]) =
>   0
>
> uname({sys="Linux", node="ip-172-31-32-236", ...}) = 0 brk(0)
>   = 0x10c1000 brk(0x10c2180)                          = 0x10c2180 arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x10c1860)      = 0 brk(0x10e3180)
>   = 0x10e3180 brk(0x10e4000)                          = 0x10e4000 open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY) = 3 fstat(3,
>   {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=99154480, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL,
>   99154480, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f46155a4000 close(3)
>   = 0 open("/etc/ld-me.so.conf", O_RDONLY) = 3 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0640, st_size=25, ...}) = 0 mmap(NULL, 4096,
>   PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) =
>   0x7f46155a3000 read(3, "/opt/me/lib\n", 4096) = 25 stat("/opt/me/lib",
>   {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0750, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0 read(3, "", 4096)
>   = 0 close(3)                                = 0 munmap(0x7f46155a3000, 4096)            = 0 stat("/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096,
>   ...}) = 0 stat("/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=12288, ...}) =
>   0 stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
>   stat("/usr/lib64", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0
>   open("/opt/me/lib", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

Can anybody tell me why system libraries are getting added ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because that is the defined behavior of ldconfig:

> ldconfig  creates  the  necessary  links  and  cache to the most
>   recent shared libraries found in the directories specified on the
>   command line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, **and in the trusted
>   directories (/lib and /usr/lib)**.  The cache is used by the run-time
>   linker, ld.so or ld-linux.so.  ldconfig checks the header and
>   filenames of the libraries it encounters  when
>          determining which versions should have their links updated.

The trusted directory list was probably updated with lib64 dirs sometime after the man page I cut'n'pasted from was written.

You could create a directory structure based on your conf file with symlinks or bind mounts pointing to the real directories and then use 
-r directory to make ldconfig build based on empty versions of the system directories.

Comment: I am having a conf file that is different from that the system provides(also with a different name).
Since, i am creating the cache newly by giving the "conf" file path. I cannot use "-n" option here.

I am seeing this issue only on Amazon-linux. On other systems when i do a "ldconfig" with only specific path set in "conf" file. I dont see the system files getting added.

So wanted to know when exactly this situation arises. So that i can debug in that direction.

Comment: I suspect it arises when the ldconfig is built to include the default paths automatically.  What does the man page on the problem system say?  You can generate your command line arguments from the conf file if you have to.

Comment: Ya.. ldconfig is built to include system libraries by default. I had to remove that part of code and compile ldconfig binary to get only the lib path that i give in the conf file.